# Stop requests to xmlrpc.php after Wordpress uninstall

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, wordpress, ddos

I had a previous installation of Wordpress in my server and after a DDOS attack, I blocked the access to the `xmlrpc.php` file from the `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files "xmlrpc.php">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Recently, I uninstalled Wordpress but still have requests to the absent file.

My error.log is full of:

```
[Tue Dec 06 15:30:20 2016] [error] [client 163.172.160.205] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/myserver.com/xmlrpc.php
[Tue Dec 06 15:30:20 2016] [error] [client 212.47.231.34] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/myserver.com/xmlrpc.php
[Tue Dec 06 15:30:20 2016] [error] [client 163.172.143.0] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/myserver.com/xmlrpc.php
[Tue Dec 06 15:30:20 2016] [error] [client 163.172.161.136] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/myserver.com/xmlrpc.php
[Tue Dec 06 15:30:21 2016] [error] [client 163.172.161.64] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/myserver.com/xmlrpc.php
```

How should I stop these requests or at least avoid their logging?

Comment: I run my servers behind CloudFlare. I would just add a rule that prevents it passing those requests on to my server. Any CDN should have similar functionality. You may also be able to do something similar on some firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this easily with fail2ban.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment or expanded to become an answer?

Comment: It answers the question posed fully.